# Curl возвращает CURLE_LOGIN_DENIED при попытке обращения к mail.ru по IMAP

Tags: c++, curl, imap

При попытке подключения к imap mail.ru выплевывает ошибку CURLE_LOGIN_DENIED, пробовал различные комбинации логина (с хостом и без) тот же результат, есть какие-нибудь идеи как это победить?
P.S. Данные точно корректные

Часть кода:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "****@mail.ru");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "****");


curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imap://imap.mail.ru");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "SEARCH NEW");

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Comment: А Curl умеет протокол imap?

Comment: да https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html

Answer (score 0):

1. [Mail.ru использует обязательный SSL/TLS](https://help.mail.ru/mail-help/mailer/popsmtp), поэтому `imaps://` а не `imap://`
2. Нужно указывать подкаталог на сервере, в данном случае inbox

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "imaps://imap.mail.ru/INBOX/"); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "SEARCH NEW");

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```